# Elixir Cannot connect to the PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've a project running on my local machine using:

```
Erlang with openssl: Version 18.0
Elixir: Version 1.3.4
```

I installed both of them using **asdf**. Everything works fine. But when I try to connect to database it always gives me the following error:

> unhandled exit at GET /ad_units/Y9Gd1kAiPCv8WOrE
>   exited in: :gen_server.call(#PID<0.469.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.0.6.2529>, true, 15000}, 5000)
>       ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
>           ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: [10, 7, 7, 18, 4, 1]
>               (postgrex) lib/postgrex/utils.ex:39: Postgrex.Utils.parse_version/1
>               (postgrex) lib/postgrex/extensions/void.ex:5: Postgrex.Extensions.Void.init/2
>               (postgrex) lib/postgrex/types.ex:56: anonymous fn/2 in Postgrex.Types.prepare_extensions/2
>               (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1115: anonymous fn/4 in Enum.into/3
>               (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1623: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
>               (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1121: Enum.into/4
>               (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:434: Postgrex.Protocol.bootstrap_send/3
>               (postgrex) lib/postgrex/protocol.ex:69: Postgrex.Protocol.connect/1
>               (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:114: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
>               (connection) lib/connection.ex:623: Connection.enter_connect/5
>               (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:239: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and PostgreSQL 10. 
BTW, I can connect to the postgres using a Ruby on Rails project and it's working fine. I tried to remove the `build` and then `mix deps.get && mix deps.compile`, but still the same.

Any idea what's the issue?

**UPDATE**

`mix.deps` dependencies:

```
defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.6"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.4"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
      {:phoenix_slime, "~> 0.6.0"},
      {:timex, "~> 2.2"},
      {:tzdata, "~> 0.1.8", override: true},
      {:timex_ecto, "~> 1.1.3"},
      # {:quantum, ">= 1.7.1"},
      {:exrm, "~> 1.0" },
      {:edeliver, ">= 1.2.10"},
      {:browser, "~> 0.1.0"}]
  end
```

Comment: It appears that the postgres version information is in a state that postgrex does not understand. There might be a few too many digits: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/master/lib/postgrex/utils.ex

Comment: @bogertron, In that case what should I do?

Comment: Why do you use ancient versions of both OTP and Elixir? What is your `mix.exs`’ dependencies section states?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I've updated the question. Added the `mix.exs` dependencies

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue is this project is stuck to very old versions of everything, including `postgrex` driver which does not support PostgreSQL 10 versions. Is there any issue to upgrade everything to somewhat more up-to-date? Or you might downgrade your PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded the postgres version from 10.7 to 9.5. It's working like a charm!

The version of `postgrex`adapter used in the project doesn’t have the upgrades to connect to *PostgreSQL* versions > 9.5.

Maybe it'll help someone else in future.

Thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin for your comment.

Comment: Strange, I have version 11.2, and it works fine. `PostgreSQL 11.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5), 64-bit`. I think you might be older versions and cannot connect to the 9.5 or above.

Comment: Correct. Older Postgrex (the library) versions could not connect to Postgres 10+. So one has to either upgrade Postgrex or downgrade Postgres.